# How do I load StringTemplates from the resource package?

Tags: java, stringtemplate-4

I have the following package structure

```
src/main/resources/shiro/definitions
```

I'd like to load the `.st` files from the resources package. I can't figure out how to get the right file path for this folder.

I'd like to do something like (snippet from the docs) to load my templates:

```
STGroup group = new STGroupFile("shiro/definitions")
ST st = group.getInstanceOf("decl");
st.add("type", "int");
st.add("name", "x");
st.add("value", 0);
String result = st.render();
```

I'd also like to get templates that I can access them at runtime when I create an executable jar.

Comment: can you try /shiro/definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must have been typing something incorrectly. I was able to get it to work.

Given,

```
src/main/resources/shiro/definitions
-- shiro.stg

src/main/resources/shiro/definitions/test
-- decl.st
-- init.st
```

I can access the templates as a folder with:

```
STGroup group = new STGroupDir("shiro/definitions/test");
ST st = group.getInstanceOf("decl");
```

I can access the group file with:

```
STGroup group = new STGroupFile("shiro/definitions/shiro.stg");
ST st = group.getInstanceOf("decl");
```

It works!